# How do I remove duplicate albums from my iPhone 5's music app?

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios, music

My issue is that my music app shows two different albums that I synced today twice, both completely identical, each having the full list of the songs. In the 'songs' view, each song is only shown once. Obviously, I have set Year, Album Artist and Album to the same values

My iOS version is 6.1.4

Advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who have this problem, the error fixed itself after a few days during a sync.